# Azure HTML Web Site (Not ASP) Could not load file or assembly System.Web.Mvc

Tags: html, azure

I have a non-asp, not asp, not .NET, not ASP.NET website (Web Site, not Web Application).  I am indeed using a Visual Studio Solution, but it is empty and I have added an "Existing Website".  There are no DLL's or anything involved.  The only purpose of the Solution is so it can load in Visual Studio and be Source Controlled in certain manners.

When I deployed the site to Azure, using Deployment Options, I received the error:

Could not load file or assembly 'System.Web.Mvc, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)

Again, This is not MVC.  This is a regular HTML Website.

Answer (score 0):

Somebody had accidentally sync'd the wrong repository to Azure previously, an ASP.NET Website.  In that case, the slot believes the site is an ASP.NET Site no matter what, and tries to build it as such.  So what I had to do is open up the console in Azure, `cd` to the "site" directory, and I did `rmdir` for the four folders there... wwwroot, deployments, repository... and some other one.  Azure automagically re-added wwwroot and deployments.  I disconnected the deployment source and re-added the correct one.  After that, it didn't try to build it like a .NET Application.